# AWS Sagemaker: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Let me prefix this by saying I'm very new to tensorflow and even newer to AWS Sagemaker.

I have some tensorflow/keras code that I wrote and tested on a local dockerized Jupyter notebook and it runs fine. In it, I import a csv file as my input.

I use Sagemaker to spin up a jupyter notebook instance with conda_tensorflow_p36. I modified the pandas.read_csv() code to point to my input file, now hosted on a S3 bucket.

So I changed this line of code from

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/input.csv", encoding="latin1")
```

to this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-sagemaker-bucket/input.csv", encoding="latin1")
```

and I get this error

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

I'm not sure if it's a permissions issue. I read that as long as I name my bucket with the string "sagemaker" it should have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull our data from S3 for example:

```
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd


# Set below parameters
bucket = '<bucket name>'
key = 'data/training/iris.csv'
endpointName = 'decision-trees'

# Pull our data from S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
f = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

# Make a dataframe
shape = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(f['Body'].read()), header=None)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks!